# Case statement inside create-table

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

How do you use the "java if-statement" in SQL => PostgreSQL, while creating a table/Column?

```
    CREATE TABLE Store(
           Discount INT 
                AS CASE 
         WHEN SOLD_Amount>100000 THEN 2
         WHEN SOLD_Amount>500000 THEN 5
         WHEN SOLD_Amount>1000000 THEN 10
         ELSE 0
     END       
           NOT NULL)
```

This is probally wrong, please tell us, the community how to do this kind of action.

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is a computed column..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for here is a computed column, which is not directly supported by Postgres.  You could implement this in a view, like so:

```
CREATE VIEW someview AS
SELECT SOLD_Amount,
     CASE 
         WHEN SOLD_Amount>100000 THEN 2
         WHEN SOLD_Amount>500000 THEN 5
         WHEN SOLD_Amount>1000000 THEN 10
         ELSE 0
     END As Discount
```

Or you could use a trigger to populate the column on insert/update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special PostgreSQL feature: "generated" columns.

Based on an existing table, say:

```
CREATE TABLE store (sold_amount int, ...):
```

You could create this special function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION store_sold_amount(rec store)
  RETURNS int LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS
 $func$
 SELECT CASE
         WHEN rec.sold_amount > 100000 THEN 2
         WHEN rec.sold_amount > 500000 THEN 5
         WHEN rec.sold_amount > 1000000 THEN 10
         ELSE 0 END;
 $func$;
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT s.amount, s.store_sold_amount
FROM   store s;
```

More under these related  questions:
[How can I create a column in postgres from values and selections based on other columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364254/how-can-i-create-a-column-in-postgres-from-values-and-selections-based-on-other)
[Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column)

Comment: This is the best solution, people can use this function in the create table statement of Store right ?

Comment: Small mistake: `THEN THEN`

Comment: @MrMe No. You can set a default value for a column in the create statement. But [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html): _The value is any variable-free expression (subqueries and cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed)_

Comment: @MrMeTumbsUp: This cannot be used in the `CREATE` statement. The functionally dependent value is not *saved*, it's generated on the fly in queries. For redundant storage I would use a *trigger*. You'll have to observe a couple of eventualities to keep your value current, though. Redundant storage in the base tables is usually not such a great idea, but there are exceptions ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*,
       CASE
           WHEN B.Table2 IS NOT NULL
               THEN 'Yes'
           ELSE 'No'
           END AS results_column_name_here

INTO new_table_name
FROM Table1 A
         LEFT JOIN Table2 B
                   ON A.col_to_join_on = B.col_to_join_on
```