# PostgreSQL Type Method

Tags: postgresql

How do I create type methods in PostgreSQL?
Lets take the following type for example:

```
create type Employee as (
name varchar(20),
salary integer)
```

How do I do this?

```
create method giveraise (percent integer) for Employee
begin
set self.salary = self.salary + (self.salary * percent) / 100;
end
```

Comment: You do realize that PostgreSQL is SQL database, and not object oriented programming framework?

Comment: Does that mean that i cant do this in postgres?

Comment: Oracle `object` types can have methods, but I am unaware of a `type` in Postgres with this behaviour. Instead you would create a function to accept the two parameters: `integer` and `Employee`.

Comment: Unlike Oracle, Postgres does not have type methods.

Comment: As a side note, what you calculate in your method doesn't make a lot of sense. Would have to be `self.salary * ((100::numeric + percent) / 100)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have been told in the comments, that Postgres doesn't have type methods.

However, Postgres supports [**attribute notation**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-FUNCTION-CALLS) for the execution of functions with a single parameter. This looks almost exactly like a method for the type. Consider this simple example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raise10(numeric) 
RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE sql AS 'SELECT $1 * 1.1';
```

Call:

```
SELECT (100).raise10;
```

Result:

```
 raise10
---------
   110.0
```

A **major limitation** is that this only works for a **single parameter**. No way to pass in additional parameters like a `percentage` for a variable raise.

Works for composite types just as well. More about "computed fields" in this related answer:
[Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)

To take this one step further, one can even call an `UPDATE` on the row and persist the change:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  name text PRIMARY KEY,
  salary numeric);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES 
  ('foo', 100)
 ,('bar', 200);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION giveraise10(employee)
RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
  UPDATE employee
  SET    salary = salary * 1.1   -- constant raise of 10%
  WHERE  name = ($1).name
  RETURNING salary;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT *, e.giveraise10 FROM employee e;
```

Result:

```
 name | salary | giveraise10
------+--------+-------------
 foo  |    100 |       110.0
 bar  |    200 |       220.0
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dfc47/1)
The `SELECT` displays the pre-UPDATE value for `salary`, but the field has actually been updated!

```
SELECT *, e.giveraise10 FROM employee e;

 name | salary 
------+--------
 foo  |  110.0 
 bar  |  220.0
```

Whether it's wise to use such trickery is for you to decide. There are more efficient and transparent ways to update a table.