# Using a for loop and if statement in postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

How come this is not working? Basically, this proc will update columns in the main buyer table to check if the user has data in other tables.

```
DO language plpgsql $$
    DECLARE 
    buyer integer;
    BEGIN
    FOR buyer IN SELECT id FROM buyers
    LOOP
      IF (SELECT count(*) FROM invoice WHERE buyer_id = buyer) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE buyers SET has_invoice = true WHERE id = buyer;
      ELSE
        UPDATE buyers SET has_invoice = false WHERE id = buyer;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
    END;
$$;
```

Comment: You don't need the loop, this can be done (much more efficiently) with a single update statement.

Comment: Also, if you run this while another connection is updating the `invoice` table, it can produce wrong results. You need to think about concurrency, or take a table lock so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what is "not working". Either way, use this equivalent `UPDATE` statement instead:

```
UPDATE buyers b
SET    has_invoice = EXISTS (SELECT 1 id FROM invoice WHERE buyer_id = b.id);
```

If you don't need redundant storage for performance, you can use a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) or *generated column* for the same purpose. Then the column `has_invoice` is calculated on the fly and always up to date. Instructions in this closely related answer:
[Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)