# set TableA boolean based on TableB record

Tags: postgresql

My data looks like this:

```
TableA
- id INT
- is_in_table_b BOOL

TableB
- id INT
- table_a_id INT
```

I accidentally wiped out the 'is_in_table_b' BOOL on my dev machine while reorganizing the data structures, and I forgot how I created it.  It's just a shortcut for some dev benchmarks.

All the "UPATE ... FROM ...." variations I tried are setting everything as "true" based on a the join.  I can't remember if I originally had a CAST in this.

Does anyone know of a simple , elegant way to accomplish this?  I just want to set `is_in_table_b` to True if the TableA.id appears in TableB.table_a_id.  I know some non-elegant ways with inner queries, but I want to remember the more-correct ways to do this.  I'm positive I had this done in an "Update From" originally.

Answer (score 2):

This one should be simple enough:

```
UPDATE tableA SET
 is_in_table_b = exists (select 1 FROM tableB WHERE table_a_id=tableA.id);
```

Comment: Whoops :)  Removed that bad link.

Comment: I think the exact syntax I wanted was the Update From `UPDATE table_a SET is_in_b = TRUE FROM table_b WHERE table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id ;`, inspired by Dan Farrel in the other answer.  This works and is succinct, but in my table structure is not nearly as efficient ( 1700ms vs 41100ms ).

Comment: @Jonathan: that's a different query. The one I suggest sets `is_in_b` to false when there's no matching entry in tableB, whereas the one you suggest leaves it in its previous, *wiped out* state (presumably NULL?) for these cases.

Comment: yes you're right. i'd have to do 2 queries, but setting all to NULL first is no real performance hit.  I think the more correct version would be this:  `UPDATE table_a SET is_in_b = 
 CASE
  WHEN b.table_a_id IS NOT NULL THEN True
  WHEN b.table_a_id IS NULL THEN False
 END
 FROM 
 table_a a
 LEFT JOIN table_b b
 ON b.table_a_id = a.id
 WHERE table_a.id = a.id
;`

Answer (score 1):

yeah, do a JOIN between the tables for an UPDATE.

the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a ( 
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  is_in_b boolean
);
CREATE TABLE table_b (
  table_a_id int
);
-- create some test data in table_a;
INSERT INTO table_a (is_in_b) VALUES (FALSE), (FALSE), (FALSE);
INSERT INTO table_a (is_in_b) SELECT FALSE 
    FROM table_a a1 
    JOIN table_a a2 
    JOIN table_a a3;
-- and create a subset of matching data in table_a;
INSERT INTO table_b (table_a_id) 
    SELECT id FROM table_a ORDER BY RAND() limit 5;
```

now the answer:

```
UPDATE table_a 
  JOIN table_b ON table_a_id = table_a.id
SET is_in_b = TRUE;
```

See the results with

```
SELECT * from table_b; 

SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE is_in_b;
```

Works on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8afc0/1  - should work in Postgres too I think.

Comment: You know that SQLFiddle supports various versions of PostgreSQL, right? Just pick from the list at the top.

Comment: Thanks. Wrong sql, right direction.  The "Update Join" is a mysql particular.  The Postgres/other format is "Update From" , which would be... `UPDATE table_a SET is_in_b = TRUE FROM table_b WHERE table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id ;`

Answer (score 1):

Consider to drop that redundant column altogether and use a view or a "generated column" instead (with the [`EXISTS` expression provided by @Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22186776/939860)). Details under this related question:
[Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268)

Just be sure to have an index on `TableB.table_a_id`.

Comment: Thanks. That's a great technique and applicable elsewhere, but not this particular situation. I'm using a pre-computed notational field for analytics in development.  Table_a is relatively small but table_b has tens-of-millions of records -- even with an index, the hit to compute it as an expression within our current SELECTS is way too much.