# Is PostgreSQL and Oracle Object-Relational storage the same as an ORM?

Tags: postgresql, orm, oracle11gr2

Is the built in ability of PostgreSQL and Oracle Object-Relational mapping the same as an ORM like Hibernate, SQLAlchemy, or Doctrine?  Are these databases queried and used just like objects you'd get back from ORMs?

EDIT:  Do I misunderstand what an ORDBMS is?  Stil learning.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/intro-whatis.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm

EDIT:  I found it here also.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object-relational_database_management_systems

Comment: Never heard of a built in ability of "PostgreSQL Object-Relational mapping". Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "O" in [ORDBMS (Object Relational Database Management System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORDBMS) refers to some object-oriented features in **PostgreSQL**:

- OIDs (mostly deprecated for non-system tables)
- [Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html)
- [Dot function call syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)
- User-definable type system including composite types
- Context-sensitive operators and functions.

It's up for debate where to draw the line exactly. Here is a [recent discussion on the pgsql-advocacy list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1335420139.28653.59.camel@jdavis#1335420139.28653.59.camel@jdavis) with more details.

All of this is **very different in nature** from "ORMs like Hibernate, SQLAlchemy or Doctrine".
An [ORM (Object-relational mapping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is trying to translate objects of the respective programming language to relations in a database.

Comment: Is this the same with Oracle?

Comment: @johnny: I am not as intimate with Oracle. The definition of an ORM (added a link) is independent of either Postgres *or* Oracle, though.

Comment: When you get time, maybe you can answer this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619257/what-is-the-difference-between-an-orm-and-an-ordbms