# What is the difference between an ORM and an ORDBMS?

Tags: orm, ordbms

They seem very similar to me.  I don't understand the difference  Maybe a programming example for ORDBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ORM is just translation layer between objects from a programming language and relations in a relational database. It is *not* an RDBMS, nothing to manage a database here, just a translation / mapping layer. Read the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orm/info) of [orm](/questions/tagged/orm).

An ORDBMS *is* an RDBMS with object-oriented features. This one actually manages your database. I have written more at [your preceding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617931/is-postgresql-and-oracle-object-relational-storage-the-same-as-an-orm/22618791#22618791).

As mentioned before, those two are **very different in nature**.