# How to write pgsql update query with string aggregate?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have update query that will manually change the field value as a unique string, the table already have a lost of data and the `id` as unique Pkey.

So I need the names should look like

```
mayname-id-1, 
mayname-id-2, 
mayname-id-3,     etc
```

I tried to update with `string_agg`, but that doesn't work in update queries

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET name = string_agg('mayname-id-', id);
```

How to construct string dynamically in an update query?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET name = 'mayname-id-' || CAST(id AS text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you should ***not*** add such a completely redundant column at all. It's cleaner and cheaper to generate it as functionally dependent value on the fly. You can use a view or a "generated column" for that. Details:

- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)

You can even have a unique index on such a functional value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation

```
UPDATE mytable SET name = 'nayname-id-' || (id :: text);
```