# Count column with name 'count' returns multiple rows. Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-9.2

I don't understand why this query:

`select count(base.*) from mytable base;`

does return multiple rows.

`select count(1) from mytable base;`

returns the proper count.

There is a column with the name `count`.

Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Here is the information from the schema:

```
table_catalog,table_schema,table_name,column_name,ordinal_position,column_default,is_nullable,data_type,character_maximum_length,character_octet_length,numeric_precision,numeric_precision_radix,numeric_scale,datetime_precision,interval_type,interval_precision,character_set_catalog,character_set_schema,character_set_name,collation_catalog,collation_schema,collation_name,domain_catalog,domain_schema,domain_name,udt_catalog,udt_schema,udt_name,scope_catalog,scope_schema,scope_name,maximum_cardinality,dtd_identifier,is_self_referencing,is_identity,identity_generation,identity_start,identity_increment,identity_maximum,identity_minimum,identity_cycle,is_generated,generation_expression,is_updatable
mydatabase,vcs,mytable,controlepunt,1,,YES,text,,1073741824,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,mydatabase,pg_catalog,text,,,,,1,NO,NO,,,,,,,NEVER,,YES
mydatabase,vcs,mytable,norm,2,,YES,text,,1073741824,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,mydatabase,pg_catalog,text,,,,,2,NO,NO,,,,,,,NEVER,,YES
mydatabase,vcs,mytable,fout,3,,YES,text,,1073741824,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,mydatabase,pg_catalog,text,,,,,3,NO,NO,,,,,,,NEVER,,YES
mydatabase,vcs,mytable,count,4,,YES,bigint,,,64,2,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,mydatabase,pg_catalog,int8,,,,,4,NO,NO,,,,,,,NEVER,,YES
mydatabase,vcs,mytable,id,5,,YES,bigint,,,64,2,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,mydatabase,pg_catalog,int8,,,,,5,NO,NO,,,,,,,NEVER,,YES
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply `select count(*) from mytable`?

Comment: Nothing, I just don't understand WHY this behaviour occurs.

Comment: Good question. That query isn't even valid ANSI SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style is apparently called *functional notation*.

It makes `table.col` and `col(table)` equivalent.

And  `table` and `table.*` return the same set of columns.

This question has more information on it: [Using functional notation in PostgreSQL queries instead of dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25396772/461499)

In the postgresql docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html

> Another option is to use functional notation for extracting an attribute. The simple way to explain this is that we can use the notations attribute(table) and table.attribute interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer - using it to extend samples for the OP. it seems not related to aggregation functions:

```
t=# create table s91("count" int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 38.981 ms
t=# insert into s91 values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT 0 3
Time: 13.929 ms
t=# select count(base.*) from s91 base;
 count 
-------
     1
     2
     3
(3 rows)

t=# alter table s91 rename COLUMN a to "manah_manah";
ALTER TABLE
Time: 1.025 ms
t=# select manah_manah(s91.*) from s91;
 manah_manah 
-------------
           1
           2
           3
(3 rows)
```

**update**: seems `column(alias_name)` is a valid syntax:

```
s=# with c(a,b) as (values(1,2),(2,3))
select a(c),(c).a from c;
 a | a 
---+---
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort! It seems the 'expression' is parsed using a preference towards column name. It somehow ignores the parentheses-part, but I haven't found it yet in Postgresql's `gram.y`

Comment: Updated sample - seems like a feature now, not the bug :)

Comment: Interesting :) I could of course switch to the `count(1)` for my application.. I hope this behavior could end up in the documentation somehow

Comment: syntactically this expression is closest to `function(record)` or even to casting `typename ( expression )` - anyway can't find anything alike in docs

Comment: IIRC column_names_as_functions is a relic from QUEL, which was closer to relational algebra. (there was some fuzz about it on the pg-hackers list too, a few months ago)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&q=QUEL+column&l=1&d=-1&s=r cant find - please share a link - I'd like to read on it