# Postgresql - full text search index - unexpected query results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a table with a bunch of cols
I have created a full text index on a table like this:

```
CREATE INDEX phrasetable_exp_idx ON msc.mytable 
USING gin(to_tsvector('norwegian', coalesce(msc.mytable.col1,'') || ' ' || 
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col2,'') || ' ' || 
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col3,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col4,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col5,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col6,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col7,'')));
```

I try some searches and they are lightning fast, however, for one particular search I don't get the expected results.
I have a row in my table where both col1 and col2 have the exact value "Importkompetanse Oslo AS"
in col3 it has the value "9999".
Only the query to_tsquery('9999') returns the row, which shows me that it does have the value "Importkompetanse Oslo AS" in the both col1 and col2, but the first two queries return no matches.

```
SELECT *
FROM msc.mytable
WHERE to_tsvector('norwegian', coalesce(msc.col1,'') || ' ' || 
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col2,'') || ' ' || 
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col3,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col4,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col5,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col6,'') || ' ' ||
                 coalesce(msc.mytable.col7,'')));
@@ --to_tsquery('Importkompetanse&Oslo&AS') -- nada
   plainto_tsquery('Importkompetanse') -- nada
   --to_tsquery('9999') -- OK!
```

Does anyone have an idea why my searches yields no results?

EDIT:

For some reason, to_tsquery returns something like this:
"'9999':9 'importkompetans':1,6"
The word importkompetanse seems to be cut off?

However, if I set it to simple instead of norwegian, I get the expected results and everything looks good. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used cross configuration between your `tsvector` and `tsquery` values. You should use consistent configuration, like:

```
select to_tsvector('norwegian', 'Importkompetanse Oslo AS')
       @@ to_tsquery('norwegian', 'Importkompetanse&Oslo&AS');
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4400)

This is why it worked with the `'simple'` configuration (that is your [default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html)).

*Note*: you can always [debug](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-debugging.html) text search with `ts_debug()`: f.ex. `'Importkompetanse'` has not been cut off, `'importkompetans'` is just the appropriate lexeme for this word (in the `'norwegian'` configuration).

*Off*: you use a really long, expression-based index, which will only be used, if you use the exact expression in your queries too. You used it right in your example, but this makes your queries really long, and if you change your index expression some time later, you need to make sure all "uses" updated as well.

You could use a simple (sql) function, to simplify your queries:

```
create or replace function col_tsvector(mytable)
  returns tsvector
  immutable
  language sql
  as $function$
return to_tsvector('norwegian',
  coalesce($1.col1, '') || ' ' || 
  coalesce($1.col2, '') || ' ' || 
  coalesce($1.col3, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce($1.col4, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce($1.col5, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce($1.col6, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce($1.col7, ''))
$function$;
```

With this, you can greatly simplify your index definition & your queries too. (You can even use the [attribute notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166268/1499698).)

Comment: Hi,thanks for valuable input, I'm new to postgres :) I'm not sure what you mean by cross config though? What I'm trying to do is to create an index that would match phrases, all words or some words and rank matches in that order, will my index do that?

Comment: And the word importkompetans is not a valid word in norwegian we have compound words, importkompetanse is the valid word here. Importkomtetans would be the same as import competenc in english, missing the last letter.

Comment: @LarsAnundskås by *cross* I mean, you should use the exact same configuration for `to_tsvector()` & `to_tsquery()` calls, like in my example (you omitted the configuration parameter from your calls of `to_tsquery()`, which means PostgreSQL will use the default config for that call) -- `importkompetans` is not word, it's the lexeme of (a) word(s): it helps the full text search engine to recognize similarities, like plural & inflected forms, etc.