# PostgreSQL: Calculated field in JSON

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Is there a way to calculate a field that is in JSON. Here is how my table is setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
     id int not null,
     data JSONB
)
```

Here is the document I am inserting

```
{
     'name': "test name",
     'age': 46,
     'heartrate': 211,
     'heartrateminuseage': function(){ return this.heartrate - this.age; }
}
```

How can I make something like this work?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have data like:

```
CREATE TABLE test1(id INT NOT NULL, data JSONB);

INSERT INTO test1(id, data)
VALUES (1,'{"name": "test name",
            "age": 46,
            "heartrate": 211}'),
      (2,'{"name": "test name2",
           "age": 50,
           "heartrate": 200,
           "heartrateminuseage": 1000}');
```

To calculate `"heartrateminuseage"` you could use extract values first and set using [`jsonb_set`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT id, data
   ,jsonb_set(data,'{"heartrateminuseage"}',
              to_jsonb((data->>'heartrate')::int - (data ->>'age')::int),
              true) AS data_2
FROM test1;
```

Output:

[image]

As for `calculated column`:

1. Create a view

```
  CREATE VIEW wv_test1
  AS
    SELECT id
      ,jsonb_set(data,'{"heartrateminuseage"}',
                 to_jsonb((data->>'heartrate')::int - (data ->>'age')::int),
                 true) AS data
    FROM test1;
```

2. Create a trigger that will update column
3. Create a function

More info: *[Computed / calculated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql)* and *[Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column)*