# Pass table name used in FROM to function automatically?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function, parameter-passing

Working with PostgreSQL 9.6.3. I am new to functions in databases.

Let's say there are multiple tables of item numbers. Each one has the item number, the item cost and several other columns which are factored into the "additional cost". I would like to put the calculation into a function so I can call it for any of these tables.

So instead of:

```
SELECT 
    itemnumber, 
    itemname, 
    base, 
    CASE 
        WHEN labor < 100 AND overhead < .20 THEN
        WHEN .....
        WHEN .....
        WHEN .....
        .....
    END AS add_cost,
    gpm
FROM items1;
```

I can just do:

```
SELECT 
    itemnumber, 
    itemname, 
    base, 
    calc_add_cost(),
    gpm
FROM items1;
```

If I want to be able to use it on any of the `item` tables, I guess I would need to set a `table_name` parameter that the function takes since adding the table name into the function would be undesirable to say the least.

```
calc_add_cost(items1)
```

However, is there a simpler way such that when I call `calc_add_cost()` it will just use the table name from the `FROM` clause?

```
SELECT ....., calc_add_cost(item1) FROM item1
```

Just seems redundant.

I did come across a few topics with titles that sounded like they addressed what I was hoping to accomplish, but upon reviewing them it looked like they were a different issue.

Comment: You may consider passing the row, or even just the two param values like ´calc_add_cost(labor, overhead)´. If you get the table, you would have to re-query it (and then you need to know which row to use..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even emulate a "computed field" or "generated column" like you had in mind. Basics here:

- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)

Simple demo for *one* table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_cost(items1)  -- function name = default col name
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN $1.labor < 100 AND $1.overhead < .20 THEN numeric '1'
--      WHEN .....
--      WHEN .....
--      WHEN .....
        ELSE numeric '0'  -- ?
    END;
$func$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT *, t.add_cost FROM items1 t;
```

Note the table-qualification in `t.add_cost`. I only demonstrate this syntax variant since you have been asking for it. My advise is to use the less confusing standard syntax:

```
SELECT *, add_cost(t) AS add_cost FROM items1 t;  -- column alias is also optional
```

**However**, SQL is a strictly typed language. If you define a particular row type as input parameter, it is bound to this particular row type. Passing **various whole table types** is more sophisticated, but still possible with **polymorphic** input type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_cost(ANYELEMENT)  -- function name = default col name
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN $1.labor < 100 AND $1.overhead < .20 THEN numeric '1'
--      WHEN .....
--      WHEN .....
--      WHEN .....
        ELSE numeric '0'  -- ?
    END;
$func$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Same call for any table that has the columns `labor` and `overhead` with matching data type.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9f93bd77f25110420f639733f2bb0295)*

Also see the related simple case passing simple values here:

- [How to put part of a SELECT statement into a Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165108/how-to-put-part-of-a-select-statement-into-a-postgres-function/46165525#46165525)

For even more complex requirements - like also returning various row types - see:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)