# Aggregate column from CTE cannot be used in WHERE clause in the query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

My query follows this structure:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT t1.x, COUNT(t1.y) AS count
    FROM table1 t1
    GROUP BY t1.x
)
SELECT CTE.x, CTE.count AS newCount, t2.count AS oldCount
FROM table2 t2 JOIN CTE ON t2.x = CTE.x
WHERE t2.count != CTE.count;
```

I get the following error: `[42803] ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

It looks like the `CTE.count` is the aggregate that triggers this error. Aren't CTEs supposed to be calculated before the main query? How to rewrite the query to avoid this?

PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5), 64-bit

Comment: What happens if you skip the CTE, and instead JOIN the subquery?

Comment: @jarlh Same error

Comment: Might be a  side effect of the CTE optimization (which flattens the CTE). You can try `with cte as MATERIALIZED (..) ...` - if that fixes the problem I would consider it a bug that should be reported (after you checked the most recent minor version of whatever major version you are using)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately, same result

Comment: Sometimes giving the optimizer a *row goal* can help, eg adding *limit 1000000*

Comment: @Stu That doesn't seem to work too

Comment: Just a guess, count is a keyword, name your alias differently.. AS sth_that_is_not_count

Comment: This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7a8778d840b41593c48d91846a4e1bb1) has no issues

Comment: Hmm, [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=378aa1f3d780dbf964e36f2c83d905cb)

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL and Teradata has COUNT as reserved word, but all(?) others seem to have it as a non-reserved keyword. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: That wiki page is clearly wrong, *count* is an aggregate function in all of them!

Comment: It was a typo after all

Comment: @Stu, wrong?!? Builtin functions can be named using reserved or non-reserved keywords - ANSI/ISO SQL says count is reserved, but most vendors don't.

Comment: Ah yes ok I misunderstood what you meant by reserved, it's whether it requires it to be specifically delimted, eg in some databases I could alias a column as "count" and it be fine but not "key".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `t2.count` is being interpreted as an [aggregate COUNT() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47229778/count-aggregate-dot-count-syntax-count), and your t2 table does not have a column called `count`.

Make sure that your table does actually have a `count` column, or make sure to compute it's aggregate count on another CTE before joining, and then comparing the the results. Also avoid using the alias "count", like the following:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT t1.x, COUNT(t1.y) AS total
    FROM table1 t1
    GROUP BY t1.x
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT t2.x, COUNT(t2.y) AS total
    FROM table2 t2
    GROUP BY t2.x
)
SELECT 
    CTE1.x, 
    CTE1.total AS newCount, 
    CTE2.total AS oldCount
FROM 
    CTE2 
    JOIN CTE1 ON CTE2.x = CTE1.x
WHERE 
    CTE2.total != CTE1.total;
```

Comment: Haha, it is riduculous! I've thought I had a `count` column, but it was actually called `value`. Silly mistake

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is the "t2.count" that causes the issue.

On [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/3532) I can reproduce the issue ONLY when there is no column named "count" in the table2.

In other words, the error occurs only when table 2 defined like that:

```
create table table2 (x int, y int);
```

However if I added the "count" column, the error is gone

```
create table table2 (x int, y int, count int);
```

I believe when there is no such column, the postgres handles "count" as an aggregate function and throws the error.

So, my solution would be to check if such column is present and to never use preserved keywords as column names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name exactly what I meant. Once column "count" is present in the table, error is gone-

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've accepted the other answer though, because it provides more info about how it works

Comment: @AndrewVershinin да без проблем, this is your question, so it's up to you