# Can a function taking a table as parameter be declared as IMMUTABLE?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose a table defined like this :

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    active BOOLEAN
    ,deceased BOOLEAN
);
```

I define a function specific to that table (I don't remember how this is called nor can I find it in the `CREATE FUNCTION` documentation or search engine) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION isvisible(clients) RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN $1.active AND NOT $1.deceased;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

I then get the list of clients with :

```
SELECT * FROM clients c WHERE c.isvisible;
```

In the actual table, there are several fields that could change the *visible* status of the record (mainly in the list of clients). I am planning to have such function so that the *visible* status is consistent across the application.

1. Is it safe to declare such a function as IMMUTABLE ? I am wondering because any *real* field (ie: `active` or `deceased`) could potentially change within a transaction.
2. I would like to minimize the performance degradation that such function might induce. And since I have several cases where I'd like to implement such helper functions, I'd like to hear your advices before generalizing the concept.

Comment: BTW, what is the name of such functions so that I can search information ?

Comment: This PostgreSQL oddity is called `attribute notation`. You can find explanations and examples from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql)

Comment: In PostgreSQL's documentation, it can be found [at the end of the 8.16.5 paragraph](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, you should make that a `language sql` function so it can be [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_conditions_for_scalar_functions)

```
CREATE FUNCTION isvisible(p_row clients) 
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $BODY$
  select p_row.active AND NOT p_row.deceased;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE sql 
STABLE;
```

Even if it's not inlined, a SQL function is still more efficient then a PL/pgSQL function (see e.g. [here](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/stored-functions/))

---

As pointed out by Laurenz Albe in the comments, it **is** safe to mark that function immutable.

Comment: I agree with the SQL function for inling, but the function is *definitely* `IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: hmm, so passing a row to a function isn't considered a "database lookup"?

Comment: No, `clients` is a composite type. The function does not look up the table, it just extracts the elements from the composite type.