# Is it possible to call a function/procedure in postgres without braces?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, plpgsql

I am working on DB migration from Oracle to Postgres and came across a situation where a legacy Java code is calling a stored procedure from Oracle. It is a simple call without parentheses like this : `Mgr.AdmSP.myproc = ad.ctlpk.proc`
where `ad` is schema name, `ctlpk` is Package name and `proc` is Stored Procedure in Oracle

we have migrated procedure `proc` to Postgres but when it comes to calling, Postgres expects **`()`** for procedure or function calls even if it does not take any parameters.
So we tried to run it like this : `Mgr.AdmSP.myproc = ad_ctlpk.proc()`. Here `ad_ctlpk` is postgres schema name. After executing we are getting error : `syntax error at or near "("`.
Since this is a database migration only, we are not expected to make any changes to other components except database objects. Is there a way to mimic the Oracle like procedure calling style in Postgres?
Like Postgres have function `now()` and `current_timestamp` which perform same functionality but with different syntax. I am using Postgres Ver 11.11.

Adding some details as per comments for more details. In Oracle, it is defined as `FUNCTION Proc RETURN INT` and as of now we converted it into Postgres function as
`CREATE FUNCTION ad_ctlpk.proc() RETURNS INTEGER`

I am not sure about the Framework and other java code details since I dont have access to Java code. We have access to executables only, which when executed gives below error

```
[[AdmThread 1] [WARN:AbstractThreadedPublisherManager$ExceptionHandlingThreadGroup:48] Error in thread AdmThread 1 : Problem in doWork
  Caused by: Problem running proc procedures
  Caused by: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 38, State: 42601, ErrorCode: 0
com.ubs.datait.common.distribution.exception.DistributionRuntimeException: Problem in doWork
        at common.distribution.manager.AdmThread.doWork(AdmThread.java:72)
        at common.distribution.common.AbstractDistributionThread.run(AbstractDistributionThread.java:30)
Caused by: common.distribution.exception.DistributionRuntimeException: Problem running proc procedures
        at common.distribution.manager.AdmThread.runAdminProc(AdmThread.java:100)
        at common.distribution.manager.AdmThread.doWork(AdmThread.java:67)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("                                                                                         
  Position: 38
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
```

---

**Update:** :

> Since Postgres does not support creating/calling functions without braces `()`,  we finally had to ask for changes in java code to add `()` to the function calls where required.

Comment: Are you calling the procedure from Java client code via JDBC or from a PL/Java stored procedure?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe We have jar file created for java component which is calling the procedure via JDBC

Comment: That doesn't look like JDBC code. Please tag the API and framework that you are using and edit the question to show some more of your code for context.

Comment: `ad_ctlpk.proc()` can't be a procedure because the way you use it, suggests that it's actually a function. But no, there is no way to call a Postgres function (or procedure) without the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name.  Yes you are correct. Proc was a function in Oracle, defined as   FUNCTION Proc RETURN INT  . As of now we converted it into Postgres function as CREATE FUNCTION ad_ctlpk.proc() RETURNS INTEGER. But if required we can convert it into procedure

Comment: A function is the correct thing to use if you want to return something. But it's impossible to call it without the parentheses. You will have to change your code

Comment: To address the question in the title: it *is* possible by using "attribute notation". See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166268/939860 But that's probably not applicable to your case. (And I wouldn't advise to use it either way.)