# What is the difference between referencing a column using "()" and "."?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I was trying to create a join table using the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE directors_and_films(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
directors_id int REFERENCES directors.id
films_id int REFERENCES films.id,
);
```

This causes Postgres to respond with:

> ```
> ERROR: schema "films" does not exist
> ```

When I change it to:

```
CREATE TABLE directors_films (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  director_id integer REFERENCES directors (id),
  film_id integer REFERENCES films (id)
);
```

The code executes fine.

My question is what is the difference between accessing a column using `()` as opposed to a period? What are the differences between these two in SQL generally?

Comment: the syntax is `schema_name.table_name (column_name)`

Comment: If I was creating a composite table (not sure what the technical term is) and I said ```FROM directors_and_films JOIN directors ON directors_and_films.director_id = directors.id``` why would this work but the example above does not?

Comment: in this scenario you have already mentioned `table1 JOIN table2` then in the `ON` clause its the alias of those tables. Completely different usages. This is usually done like so: `FROM directors_and_films dfs JOIN directors ds ON dfs.director_id = ds.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres does indeed support functional notation *and* attribute notation for column references. So this *works* for a table `tbl` with a column `col`:

```
SELECT col(tbl) FROM tbl;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-COMPOSITE-FUNCTIONS)

> but this usage is deprecated since it's easy to get confused

See:

- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)

But that has no bearing on the case at hand. The short syntax for FK constraints in a `CREATE TABLE` statement requires parentheses around the referenced column. (The *column* constraint like in your example, can only reference a single column, obviously.) Attribute notation like you tried (`directors.id`) is a syntax error in this spot.
That's all there is to this. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> `REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE ]`